# I want to compare images that I reconstructed using gridding algorithm. How do I do that with MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, medical, spiral, gridding

I am currently working on a project related to motion artifacts in MR images. I have some MR images and i'm extracting data from those images using different trajectories (e.g. Spiral, Radial etc) and reconstructing them using gridding algorithm. Now I need to analyze the quality of the reconstruction by comparing the reconstructed and the original image. What might be some good ways to comapre images under such scenario?

Comment: Mean square error is the standard comparison algorithm for this kind of stuff. You'll see PSNR suggested as well, but that is just a meaningless mapping of the MSE.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already have MSE on my mind. Just want to explore some other options before deciding which could be best for this problem.